# Using a variable outside its function

Tags: javascript, function, error-handling, infinite-recursion

I want to use the `checkedCount` variable inside of the `generatePassword` function in order to not call the function `matrixEffect` at the end of `generatePassword` if the value of `checkedCount` is 0.

I used the argument `checkedCountValue` to be able to use the variable outside its function. But because I'm calling the `generatePassword` function at the end of `updateSafetyIndicator` I'm receiving the error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" due to an infinite call of these functions.

```
const lengthSlider = document.querySelector(".length-wrapper input"),
options = document.querySelectorAll(".container input"),
generateBtn = document.querySelector(".generate-btn"),
copyBtn = document.querySelector(".copy-btn"),
passwordSafetyIndicator = document.querySelector(".safety-indicator"),
passwordInput = document.querySelector(".display-font");

const characters = {
    lowercase: "abcdefghijkilmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    uppercase: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    digits: "0123456789",
    specials: "^!$%&|[](){}:;.,*+-#@<>~"
}

// generate password

function generatePassword(checkedCountValue) {
    let staticPassword = "",
    randomPassword = "",
    passwordLength = lengthSlider.value;
    options.forEach(option => {
        if(option.checked) {
            staticPassword += characters[option.id];
        }
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
        randomPassword += staticPassword[Math.floor(Math.random() * staticPassword.length)];
    }

    passwordInput.innerText = randomPassword;

    if (checkedCountValue > 0) {
        matrixEffect(randomPassword);
    } 

    updateSafetyIndicator();
}



// matrix effect

const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let interval = null;

function matrixEffect(password) {  
    let iteration = 0;
    
    clearInterval(interval);
    
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      passwordInput.innerText = passwordInput.innerText
        .split("")
        .map((letter, index) => {
          if(index < iteration) {
            return password[index];
          }
        
          return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
        })
        .join("");
      
      if(iteration >= lengthSlider.value){ 
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      
      iteration += 1 / 3;
    }, 30);
  };

// safety indicator update

function updateSafetyIndicator() {

    var uppercaseCheck = document.getElementById("uppercase");
    var lowercaseCheck = document.getElementById("lowercase");
    var digitsCheck = document.getElementById("digits");
    var specialsCheck = document.getElementById("specials");
    var passwordLength = lengthSlider.value;
    var checkedCount = 0;
    
    if (uppercaseCheck.checked) {
        checkedCount++;
    }

    if (lowercaseCheck.checked) {
        checkedCount++;
    }

    if (digitsCheck.checked) {
        checkedCount++;
    }

    if (specialsCheck.checked) {
        checkedCount++;
    }

    if (checkedCount == 0) {
        passwordInput.innerText = "Please select first...";
    }

    else if (checkedCount == 1) {
        passwordSafetyIndicator.id = "veryweak";
    }

    else if (checkedCount == 2) {
        passwordSafetyIndicator.id = "weak";
    }

    else if (checkedCount == 3) {
        passwordSafetyIndicator.id = "medium";
    }

    else if (checkedCount == 4) {
        passwordSafetyIndicator.id = "strong";
    }

    if (checkedCount == 4 && passwordLength >= 10) {
        passwordSafetyIndicator.id = "verystrong";
    }

    if (checkedCount == 3 && passwordLength >= 10) {
        passwordSafetyIndicator.id = "strong";
    }

    if (checkedCount == 2 && passwordLength >= 10) {
        passwordSafetyIndicator.id = "medium";
    }

    if (checkedCount == 1 && passwordLength >= 10) {
        passwordSafetyIndicator.id = "weak";
    }

    generatePassword(checkedCount);
}

// slider length update
function updateSlider() {
    document.querySelector(".length-wrapper span").innerText = (lengthSlider.value);
}

updateSlider();


// copy password
function copyPassword(htmlElement) {
    if (!htmlElement) {
        return;
    }

    let password = passwordInput.innerText;

    let inputPassword = document.createElement("input");
    inputPassword.setAttribute("value", password);
    document.body.appendChild(inputPassword);
    inputPassword.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    inputPassword.parentNode.removeChild(inputPassword);
    passwordInput.innerText = "COPIED";

    setTimeout (() => {
        passwordInput.innerText = password;
    }, 1300);
}

copyBtn.onclick = function () {
    copyPassword(passwordInput);
}


    

lengthSlider.addEventListener("input", updateSlider);
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", generatePassword);
```

Comment: This is somewhat confusing code to follow. Right now there's no "escape clause" from the recursive functions--they unconditionally call each other. If you want that to not happen you need to put a check function in somewhere.

Comment: I'm new to the game so don't mind the mess. What should the check function contain?

Comment: Whatever you want to use to make the infinite recursion stop.

Comment: is there a better way to use a variable outside its function than the one I used in this example that wouldnt cause this infinite recursion

Comment: The infinite recursion happens because the two methods **always** call each other--there's no terminating condition that makes one not call the other *(I think)*. You mentioned something about `checkedCount` being the gate, but it's not used to not call the recursive function--only `matrixEffect`, which isn't recursive.